# Checking if a value is numerical in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2.

df1:

```
col1 <- c('30','30','30','30')
col2 <- c(3,13,18,41)
col3 <- c("heavy","light","blue","black")
df1 <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3)

>df1
  col1 col2  col3
1   30    3 heavy
2   30   13 light
3   30   18  blue
4   30   41 black
```

df2:

```
col1 <- c('10',"NONE")
col2 <- c(21,"NONE")
col3 <- c("blue","NONE")
df2 <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3)

>df2
  col1 col2 col3
1   10   21 blue
2 NONE NONE NONE
```

I wrote a bit of script that says; if a value in col3 is equal to "light", I want to remove that row and all subsequent rows in the dataframe.  So df1 would look like:

```
  col1 col2  col3
1   30    3 heavy
```

And there would be no changes to df2 (as it has no matches to "light" in col3).

I have stated there are two separate df's above as two examples, but the script below just refers to a general "df" to save me copying and pasting the same bit of code twice with df1 repalced with df2.

```
phrase=c("light")
start_rownum=which(grepl(phrase, df[,3]))
end_rownum=nrow(df)
end_rownum=as.numeric(end_rownum)
if(start_rownum > 0){
   df=df[-c(start_rownum:end_rownum),]
}
```

This script works fine with df1, as the start_rownum has a numerical value.  However, I get the following error with df2:

```
Error in start_rownum:end_rownum : argument of length 0
```

Instead of saying "if(start_rownum > 0)", is there some way to check if start_rownum has a numerical value?  I can't find a working solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `"NONE"` use `NA`, e.g., `c(10, NA)`. If this is data you import, set the `na.string` parameter during import. Then the column will be numeric and R offers many facilities for dealing with `NA` values, such as `na.omit` or `is.na`.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who has a similar problem, I just solved it:

Use the phrase

```
if (length(start_rownum)>0 & is.numeric(start_rownum))
```